# RuntimeError: Encountered unresolved custom op: Normalize.Node number 0 (Normalize) failed to prepare

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to implement smart reply https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/smart_reply/overview concept in Python. You can download tflite model file here https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tflite/smartreply_1.0_2017_11_01.zip.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="smartreply.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

While using above code, i'm getting this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smart_reply.py", line 6, in <module>
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/lite/python/interpreter.py", line 244, in allocate_tensors
    return self._interpreter.AllocateTensors()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.py", line 106, in AllocateTensors
    return _tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.InterpreterWrapper_AllocateTensors(self)
RuntimeError: Encountered unresolved custom op: Normalize.Node number 0 (Normalize) failed to prepare.
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: To use this you would need to use a custom built pip package. See the installation instructions for TensorFlow https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source. Also, you need to change the ops included in your built version of TF lite. The Java version has a custom op resolver see  the build here: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/smart_reply/android/app/libs/cc/BUILD  ...  You can see where the ops are registered here: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/smart_reply/android/app/libs/cc/predictor.cc#L77

Comment: This issue is related to converter.allow_custom_ops=True while converting the model

Comment: @aselle Thanks for you reply. I've downloaded smartreply.tflite model directly from their samples. So if we change the code related to custom ops, then i've to re build the tflite model? Also if i removed the custom ops code then the smart reply predictor will work perfectly?

Comment: @GunjanDave Yes. But i'm using smartreply.tflite downloaded file directly from their samples. I've not built that model file. But above option is to set before build tflite model.