# Throwing error: Encountered unresolved custom op: Normalize.Node number 0 (Normalize) failed to prepare

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

For my previous question
[RuntimeError: Encountered unresolved custom op: Normalize.Node number 0 (Normalize) failed to prepare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59627407/runtimeerror-encountered-unresolved-custom-op-normalize-node-number-0-normali),
i've received below answer.

> To use this you would need to use a custom built pip package. See the installation instructions for TensorFlow tensorflow.org/install/source. Also, you need to change the ops included in your built version of TF lite. The Java version has a custom op resolver see the build here: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/smart_reply/android/app/libs/cc/BUILD. You can see where the ops are registered here: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/smart_reply/android/app/libs/cc/predictor.cc#L77

But i've downloaded smartreply.tflite model directly from their
samples. So if we change the code related to custom ops, then i've to
re build the tflite model? Also if i removed the custom ops code then
the smart reply predictor will work perfectly?

Comment: hi Bernardo - I'm having the same issue. were you able to solve this? if so - how did you do this?